# In "The Matrix Resurrections", how did these characters end up back in the Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix Resurrections*, how did Smith and Morpheus end up back in the Matrix?

I have no idea how Smith survived. And the entire situation with Morpheus was confusing to me. How did he end up as an agent, and why was he that "see-through" thing in the real world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understand that both Smith and Morpheus are characters who can be portrayed in multiple ways.

### Agent Smith

> [Hugo Weaving’s Agent Smith](https://www.gamesradar.com/uk/matrix-resurrections-ending-explained-neo-trinity-morpheus/) was destroyed by Neo in *Matrix: Revolutions*. In this new version of the Matrix seen in *Matrix: Resurrections*, the machines have created a new version of Smith to keep Neo at bay. Like Weaving’s Smith, Groff’s Smith soon evolves beyond the machine’s programming and control, and history sort of repeats itself. While Weaving’s Smith was absolutely against Neo, Groff’s Smith eventually sides with Neo. But in any case, Smith exists within the Matrix as digital information (his ability to leave via possessing others’ minds notwithstanding), which is merely presented to us in visual form because we can visualize the root machine code. Think of Smith as a computer program with Weaving being v1.0, and Groff being 2.0.

### Morpheus

> Lawrence Fishburne's Morpheus died in the fight against the machines. The new version of Morpheus is not a real person, but a piece of code, created by the machines to be a new agent; a mixture of the original Morpheus’ role and Agent Smith. The Morpheus of *Matrix: Resurrections* is a completely different character from the original Matrix trilogy’s Morpheus, but shares the same “Morpheus” name. It’s like if you met someone named “Jim” in a Starbuck’s and see a completely different guy at Walmart also named Jim — they’re different people. The Morpheus of *Matrix: Resurrections* being a digital program is able to manifest an avatar in the real world by controlling nano magnets in the real world to give him a physical form which his program is then able to manipulate, for example to create a physical emulation of human beings. Think how Voltron unites to form a giant robot; Morpheus unites his nano magnets in the real world to create a body. These nano magnets appear to have interesting features such as transparency.

Comment: If Morpheus was just a piece of code, then how was he able to take a red pill and be freed?

Comment: What the red pill even is in _Resurrections_, as well as what it does, and/or whom it was ever “for” are certainly interesting questions.

Comment: He was two layers deep, wasn't he? He escaped Neo's simulation and was then able to access the "real" matrix and real world.

Comment: My understanding was that Morpheus was an artifact of Neo's "modal", not an intentional creation of the machines. The existence of that modal and Morpheus' escape with Babs is what kicks off the plot and allows Neo to be freed.